# Need help restoring a tar backup

Tags: sudo, data-recovery, tar

I managed to borde my sudo... I have a backup of the system that I can try restore. However, since sudo is broken I can't overwrite files that are protected.

Guidelines I tired to follow when making and restoring the backup: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR

Basically I want to run

```
sudo tar -xvpzf /path/to/backup.tar.gz -C / --numeric-owner
```

Which generates:

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't resore a full system backup this way. You need to boot from a LiveUSB.

Comment: Can you boot to runlevel 1?   Do you have another account with `sudo` privilieges, or root account enabled?  Otherwise I'd boot a 'live' system & fix the issue (which I take it is you didn't use `visudo` which evaluates any changes before exiting your chosen editor).

Comment: Most likely OP ran something like `chmod 777 -R /`

Comment: @Pilot6 yep, `chown user1:user1 -R /` RIP

Comment: Why so many people shoot in their foot?

Comment: @Pilot6 To my defense I did this by after writing `/` I pressed `Q` which is only one folder and then quick tab and enter key. However the Q seems to never have registered... Maybe I missed the key or something.

Comment: @Pilot6 post it as a solution and I accept it. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can't restore a full-system backup from within a broken system. Especially when `sudo` is broken.

Yoг need to boot from something else, like Ubuntu LiveUSB. Then you'll be able to restore.